# C POSIX periodic task

Tags: c, parameters, posix, real-time

I want to implement a real time system on POSIX which composed of set of periodic tasks (which implement functions). How do I define the task parameters (period, deadline, cost, priority) in C POSIX program.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread,pthread_attr_t *attr,void *(*thread_func)(void*), void *thread_arg);
int pthread_exit(void *retval);
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Your question is unclear.  You quote the signatures of 3 Pthreads functions, but it is not clear that they have any relevance to the question.  You need to rewrite the question from scratch, explaining what you're trying to do and what you've tried to do and where you're having problems.  (Also, you need to choose either C or C++ — the differences are vast.  I've removed C++, but by all means switch to C++ from C.  Don't dither though; the languages are very different.)

Comment: You have reason, i put this code snippet because StackOverflow forces me to add it to publish my question which is: How do I define the task parameters (period, deadline, cost, priority) in C POSIX program ?

Comment: Are you looking at POSIX priority scheduling, or are you devising a system to simulate deadlines, costs, priorities and periods, or what?  You've not explained a thing about what you're trying to do — what problem you're trying to solve, what problems you're facing.  You've not explained what you're studying.  Maybe you need to look at the discussion of POSIX [realtime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08).  But you have to do major work on your question for it to be comprehensible, let alone appropriate for SO.

Comment: Rewrite the question — do not post the information as comments.